# How do I handle this msg: Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessage<bool>>(msg);

Tags: mvvm-light

Given this:

```
var msg = new NotificationMessage<bool>(isHead, buffer.ToString());

Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessage<bool>>(msg);
```

How do I catch this message?

I'm not sure of the Messenger.Default.Register... syntax,

or the prototype for the action method.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

D'oh, here it is:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<bool>>(this, MessageRx);

private void MessageRx(NotificationMessage<bool> msg)
```

msg.Notification is the message string, and msg.Content is the value of the bool.